# How to plya ringtone in Flutter application when app is closed?

Tags: flutter, agora.io, ringtone

I am working on a project where I am using Agora for Video calling feature. I used flutter_ringtone_player to play ringtone whenever there is a call. It works fine when app is active but it is not working in the inactive state of the app.

Can anyone suggest me How i can make it work for my project.

Comment: any solution on this question?

Comment: yes if you are using flutter v2 you can easily use fcm background services, if you are using any other service you can check out for alarm manager